# Get the distinct rows and count of distinct rows where one column value type follows the other

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
order_id | created_dt | type         |
123      | 2000-01-01 | refund       |
123      | 2000-01-01 | cancellation |
124      | 2000-01-01 | refund       |
125      | 2000-01-02 | refund       |
125      | 2000-01-02 | cancellation |
```

I need to find the distinct orders and the count of distinct orders where a refund is followed by a cancellation. Can this be done in one query or will separate queries be easier?

Maybe LAG and LEAD functions could help but I don't know how to use them so some explanation would be of help. Thanks!

This is what I've tried but it doesn't work since the sub-query returns more than one row.

```
select ORDER_ID, TYPE,
       (select next_type
           from (
                    select lead(type) over (order by ORDER_ID) as next_type
                    from table_name
                    where type = 'cancellation'
                    ))
from table_name
```

My desired result is:

```
order_id | type         |
123      | refund       |   
123      | cancellation |
125      | refund       |   
125      | cancellation |
```

and a way to count the number of these orders.

Comment: @DaleK, I'm new here. Still getting used to this site. And I can't cast a vote unless I have 15 reputations.

Comment: If both refund and cancellation happen at the same day then there is no way to check if *a refund is followed by a cancellation* because there is no other column that defines the order of the rows.

Comment: @forpas I do have a timestamp column as well. How would the query work then?

Comment: Why do you have a date *and* a timestamp column? A timestamp always includes a day. This doesn't seem to make sense. Anyway, so use the timestamp column instead of the date column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with your query is that you select rows `where type = 'cancellation'` and then you look with `LEAD` at the next row. You won't find refunds thus, but only cancellations.

Another is that your `OVER` clause is wrong. You want the next type for the same order_id (`PARTITION BY order_id`) according to the order by date (`ORDER BY created_dt`).

Well, and then you don't even look for refunds in your query.

This should work for you:

```
select
  order_id, created_dt, type
from
(
  select
    order_id, created_dt, type,
    lag(type) over (partition by order_id order by created_dt) as prev_type,
    lead(type) over (partition by order_id order by created_dt) as next_type
  from mytable
) with_prev_and_next
where type = 'refund' and next_type = 'cancellation'
   or type = 'cancellation' and prev_type = 'refund'
order by order_id, created_dt;
```

This gets you all refunds and cancellations where the former is directly followed by the latter, regardless of whether there are other types in the table. If there can be other types and the cancellation doesn't have to follow the refund *directly*, then add a where clause to the inner query in order to look at refunds and cancellations only.

As to counting these orders:

```
select count(distinct order_id) from ( <above query> ) q;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find distinct orders that are refunded followed by a cancellation fairly simply using a subselect:

```
    select distinct order_id from <table> t1 
    where type = 'refund' 
     and 
     (
         select count(*) from <table> t2 
           where t2.order_id = t1.order_id 
              and t2.type = 'cancellation' > 0
     );
```

It's trivial from there to get the count, and depending on context I would generally recommend either counting the results (if you are in programming language where you can count the results), or using a count(order_id) if not.

Comment: The query would be more readable, did you format it a little. There is a parenthesis missing. And `and (select count ...)` requires an explantion in my opinion, as the count gets implicitly converted into a boolean value by MySQL rules. And you don't check whether the cancellation actually *follows* the refund.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - fair criticism - shouldn't have written this on the run.  Formatted query and fixed it - forgot the boolean comparator (>0).  As for "follows the refund - can you see a way to do this with this table structure?  Only the date field could be used for this, and with a date only (no time), it's kind of difficult.

Comment: Oh, you are right. It totally escaped me that the sample data shows cancellation and refund on the very same day. So, indeed, "follows the refund" makes no sense then.